# Pandas find values other than date

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame in which I have columns containing dates.

I need to make sure that nothing else but dates are contained in these columns. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?
I thought about simply finding which rows contain data of a type other than date - although I don't know how to code this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you just try to convert elements into date objects, and if it fails then you have corrupted data.

Comment: It would help to see an example of what you consider to be a valid date and what is not, besides you could do `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(errors='coerce')` and then call `df.dropna()` as any invalid date strings will be converted to `NaT`

Answer (score 2):

If data not contains `NaN`s or `None`s values and need check if all string valus can be converted to `datetime` use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and parameter `errors='coerce'` what return `NaT` if some value cannot be parsed. So then add [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for mask and select with `loc`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['2015-02-04','2015-02-05','2015-02-06'],
                   'b':['2015-02-06','2015-02-06', 'u'], 
                   'c':['2015-01-01','d','2015-02-06']})
print (df)
            a           b           c
0  2015-02-04  2015-02-06  2015-01-01
1  2015-02-05  2015-02-06           d
2  2015-02-06           u  2015-02-06

cols = ['a','b','c']
mask = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce').notnull().all()
print (mask)
a     True
b    False
c    False
dtype: bool

print (df.loc[:, mask])
            a
0  2015-02-04
1  2015-02-05
2  2015-02-06
```

Or if need check if some column has already `dtype` `datetime` use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a'])
print (df)
           a           b           c
0 2015-02-04  2015-02-06  2015-01-01
1 2015-02-05  2015-02-06           d
2 2015-02-06           u  2015-02-06

print (df.dtypes)
a    datetime64[ns]
b            object
c            object
dtype: object

print (df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime']))
           a
0 2015-02-04
1 2015-02-05
2 2015-02-06
```